# Average of Monte Carlo simulations of continuous functions again continuous?

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, continuity, monte-carlo, simulation

I hope the following question is clear:

Suppose, we have a continuous functions $f:\mathbb{N}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$. Now, suppose we run Monte Carlo simulations on the function, where the input parameters are distributed according to a continuous probability distribution. Suppose we calculate the sample mean of the MC-simulations outcomes.

Would it make sense to define continuity on the entire process? What would continuity of this process actually mean? Would it make sense to define continuity on the result after infinite many MC-simulations?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "a continuous function $\Bbb{N}^2 \to \Bbb{N}$"?

Comment: Sorry for being imprecise. I mean a function $f$ that has two input parameters and that is continuous with regard to both parameters. So slight changes in either the first or the second parameter do not result in jumps.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your question that well.  From what I understand it is akin to population distribution and sampling distribution for the process.  If one is continuous, the other is continuous too.  To further describe, let us say you have normal distribution with $N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ where $\mu$ and $\sigma^2$ are true parameters, then sampling parameters $(\bar x, \bar S)$ are the for the sampling distribution.  Similarly, average of monte carlo distribution from a true probability distribution is the same as the sampling distribution with random bias (owing to pseudo random simulations) if that makes you comfortable.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, but maybe let me try to rephrase slightly. With continuity of the function $f(x,y)$, I mean that there should be no jumps if $x$ or $y$ are slightly changed. Now suppose the input parameters are distributed according to some distribution. If I sample those input parameters $n$ times, then I obtain the values $f(x_1, y_1), \dots, f(x_n,y_n)$. Now suppose I calculate the average $avg(f(x_1, y_1), \dots, f(x_n,y_n))$. Can I somehow say that this averaging function is continuos with regard to the input parameter distributions? Is that question clear?

Comment: You have just taken a multivariate function. Simply reduce it to X a single variable function, in my example , I have give such distribution for X to be $N(\mu,\sigma^2)$.  Normal distribution is continuous in the interval $(-\infty, \infty)$.  Suppose you randomly choose n values for random variable x and average that to $\bar x$.  You do this 1000 times and if you plot that histogram of this $\bar x$, you will get a normal distribution which is continuous with parameter $N(\mu,\sigma^2/n)$.  The sampling distribution function$ f(\bar x)$ is continuous too.This is true for all continuous f(x)

Comment: Thanks @satish. Is there a possibility to contact you on Skype? I guess, I get very close to understanding what you mean. Maybe we could shortly clarify on Skype, if that would work for you?